# Oracle unused cursors create overhead?

Tags: performance, oracle11g, cursor

I am working on an application that have lot of cursor and many of them are just defined in a package header and not used in package body, so does this unused cursor creates an overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declared cursor but unused cursor will create no overhead but an open but unused cursor might, a bit.

An open cursor is stored in the private SQL area of the PGA. This *"holds information about a parsed SQL statement and other session-specific information for processing."*. You can find the amount of PGA you have by querying [`V$PGASTAT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2096.htm#REFRN30180).

It's not 100% clear from Oracle's [Memory Architecture documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/memory.htm#CNCPT1237) whether opened but unused cursors store anything in the PGA. The section on the persistent area of the private SQL area of the PGA would insinuate that this is only created if you're binding any variables to your cursor; but, as the state of the cursor must be stored in order for the DB to know that it's open I'm assuming that *some* memory is used.

If a single open cursor is negatively impacting your performance I'd be horrified. This would be an indication that you've massively underestimated the size of the PGA and SGA (execution plans are stored here) that you need.

However, this strategy can backfire massively as the number of open cursors is limited by the *open_cursors* parameter, which you can find in [`V$PARAMETER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2087.htm#REFRN30176). This is an absolute upper limit on the number of open cursors you can have open. If you hit this limit you'll get ORA-01000.

**This means that you should not open cursors that you're not going to use.**

However it's also worth noting [this particular Ask Tom question/answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1089433252941#17013370083497), though it's from 2004.

> 3- If the open_cursors are increased then what will be the performance impact on the db > server and the memory usage?
>   ...
>
> Followup   April 1, 2004 - 10am UTC:
>   ...
>   ...3) if you are not hitting ora-1000, it will change nothing (since you are not using the cursors you currently have)